# How to save Dataset in temp memory of page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, report, rdlc

I have a function which call a procedure from SQL Server and return a datatable as

```
public static DataTable GetProducts(int parmCategory = -1){}
```

in my asp page I have

```
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ReportsBLL.GetProducts()));
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

which fill once in `pageload()`
this procudure takes about 8 minutes to get data from database 
and I want to make a lot of filtration in button press to filter data which comes from `GetProducts` 
and there is no logic to call procure in every filter and contact the DB

So, how can I save the data once I get it in the `pageload` and deal with it in button press filtration

Comment: Think about paging your result set/s. Server _and_ client will be better off. IMHO, based on your comment below, I'm not sure any user will actually need/be able to use, _"100000 rows"_.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much data is returning.
If its not too much, put the data into the session variable with something like this:
Set the data into a variable on page called dataSet1.

```
Session["DataSet1"] = dataSet1;
```

If the data is massive, you really want to consider having the page "refresh" between filtering.  This way you don't blow out your memory.

Comment: No my data is very big, I said it takes about 8 minutes ti load data from DB

Comment: In that case, I would suggest "refreshing" the page between each filter.  Then bring in less data by using paged queries to limit the load time.  That is set the results to return only 1000 records at a time or so.  This will speed everything up.  If you need the total of what should have returned, then get a "count" first.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what do you mean , my data above 100000 rows and It necessary to load them

Comment: I want to use this method                      `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("secret key", table, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);`
but can't recognize httpcontext have you any idea about it?

Comment: That looks like you are already caching the results.  I'm not explaining well.  Google this "paged database query asp.net".  This will allow the user of your app to interact with small sets of the data as if they were interacting with the whole returned set.

Comment: Did this get you what you needed?